# Observables in Angular / Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

So I'm just learning about observables and I'm very confused about something, I just subscribed to a url and was expecting it to run more than once but it only worked once, am I missing somethign here? This is my Page.ts:

```js
test() {
  this.testProvider.test(this.dummyData).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

And in my TestProvider.ts I have this:

```js
test(data): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('http://monitor.xxxxx.test/get-something');
}
```

Now my code is supposed to execute on button click which it does however the expected result was the console logs the output repeatedly but that didn't happen it only run once and that was it.

Comment: Observables can emit zero or more values and may or may not complete. Angular's HTTP observable emits the request's response and then completes. Completion automatically unsubscribes a subscriber.

Comment: But then isn't that just the same as using a promise?

Comment: It's similar, but a HTTP request initiated using an observable can be cancelled by unsubscribing. A request initiated using a Promise cannot be. If you are looking for an introduction to observables, [this is a good place to start](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754).

Comment: test() is called on button click() ?

Comment: Yes it is..........

Comment: Why do you expect the console logs to output more than once? I'm assuming you click the button only once?